# Как на google maps узнать номера маршруток проезжающих через конкретную остановку?

Tags: google-maps-api

Можно ли на google maps узнать номера маршруток которые проезжають через конкретную остановку, имея при этом все данные об остановке

```
 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(main_map_data.map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: lat,
    radius: 300,
    types: ['bus_station']
  }, processResults);


function processResults(results, status, pagination) {
  if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    return;
  } else {
    createMarkers(results);
  }
}
function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for(var i = 0; places.length > i; ++i){
         service.getDetails({
                placeId: obj.place_id
              }, function(place, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                  var p = place;
                }
              });
  }
}
}`
```